# How to add a "Read More" button at the bottom of a textView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios10

I have problem to add a clickable "read more" button in `textView` at the end of the `textView`. My `textView` is in a custom cell. The height of the view changes depending on the text it displays. I have set 3 lines as the maximum for the `textView`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [ask] and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you. What have you tried? What do you have so far?

Comment: Please try this github repo : https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView